# How to get the individual media id for each image in Instagram for android

Tags: android, instagram

I have used this link to http://b2cloud.com.au/uncategorized/instagram-integration-in-an-android-app to authorize and get the images and comments from instagram , I am displaying the 
details in  a list view now i require the media id of each of the displayed . can you please suggest how to do it or can you suggest any possible way to send comment or like a image instagram

thanks in advance